# In PHP How can I split an associative by key or value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and I need to split that array by key(`TFvchBBAAA/BDQC1HlAAAA4==`) or value(`PNQ_NAG`). How can I do that in the best way?

Here Is the array:

```
$arr=array(
    ['TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA1=='] => 'DEL_NAG',
    ['TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA2=='] => 'NAG_GOI',
    ['TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA98=='] => 'GOI_AMD',
    ['TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA981=='] => 'AMD_MAA',
    ['TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA3=='] => 'MAA_PNQ',
    ['TFvchBBAAA/BDQC1HlAAAA4=='] => 'PNQ_NAG',
    ['TFvchBBAAA/BDQC1HlAAAA6=='] => 'NAG_DEL',
  )
```

I have the value of key: `TFvchBBAAA/BDQC1HlAAAA4==` and its value `PNQ_NAG`, where from I need to split it. Required solution should like this:

```
$arr=array(

    [1]=>array(
        ['TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA1=='] => 'DEL_NAG',
        ['TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA2=='] => 'NAG_GOI',
        ['TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA98=='] => 'GOI_AMD',
        ['TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA981=='] => 'AMD_MAA',
        ['TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA3=='] => 'MAA_PNQ',
     ),
    [2]=>array(
        ['TFvchBBAAA/BDQC1HlAAAA4=='] => 'PNQ_NAG',
        ['TFvchBBAAA/BDQC1HlAAAA6=='] => 'NAG_DEL',
    )
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: That does not sound that hard; what do you have so far and what is the problem with it?

Comment: _"key(TFvchBBAAA/BDQC1HlAAAA4==) **or** value(PNQ_NAG)"_ or _"TFvchBBAAA/BDQC1HlAAAA4== **and** its value PNQ_NAG"_ ?

Comment: conditional statements inside a `foreach($arr as $key => $value)` loop will do just fine

Comment: I just need to break or split that array I have both key and value. You can use the key to split it.

Comment: Hi, frz3993  have you try by the loop, sorry but the loop could not do that. If you have to try and return the desired o/p then please send me sample code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$arr = array(
    'TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA1==' => 'DEL_NAG',
    'TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA2==' => 'NAG_GOI',
    'TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA98==' => 'GOI_AMD',
    'TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA981==' => 'AMD_MAA',
    'TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA3==' => 'MAA_PNQ',
    'TFvchBBAAA/BDQC1HlAAAA4==' => 'PNQ_NAG',
    'TFvchBBAAA/BDQC1HlAAAA6==' => 'NAG_DEL',
  );

$result = array();
$part = 1;

foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
    if ($key == 'TFvchBBAAA/BDQC1HlAAAA4==' || $value == "PNQ_NAG") {
        $part = 2;
    }
    $result[$part][$key] = $value;
}

print_r($result);
```

And results:

```
Array ( 
[1] => Array ( 
    [TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA1==] => DEL_NAG 
    [TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA2==] => NAG_GOI 
    [TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA98==] => GOI_AMD 
    [TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA981==] => AMD_MAA 
    [TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA3==] => MAA_PNQ 
  ) 
[2] => Array ( 
    [TFvchBBAAA/BDQC1HlAAAA4==] => PNQ_NAG 
    [TFvchBBAAA/BDQC1HlAAAA6==] => NAG_DEL 
  )
)
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not returned as the accepted result.

Comment: I don't think it can possible by the loop.

Comment: @Brijesh Singh, you want to split the array into two parts when you find `$key = 'TFvchBBAAA/BDQC1HlAAAA4=='` or `$value = 'PNQ_NAG'` ?

Comment: Yes, @vpalade.split the array into two parts when we find $key or $value

Comment: And what is wrong with my answer? What are test data that my code doesn't split correctly?

Comment: Hi @ vpalade, now you given sample code is working after updating the code. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit long but maybe useful

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    'TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA1==' => 'DEL_NAG',
    'TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA2==' => 'NAG_GOI',
    'TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA98==' => 'GOI_AMD',
    'TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA981==' => 'AMD_MAA',
    'TFvchBBAAA/BBQC1HlAAAA3==' => 'MAA_PNQ',
    'TFvchBBAAA/BDQC1HlAAAA4==' => 'PNQ_NAG',
    'TFvchBBAAA/BDQC1HlAAAA6==' => 'NAG_DEL',
);

$k = 'TFvchBBAAA/BDQC1HlAAAA4==';
$v = 'DEL_NAG';

function splitArray($arr, $splitByKey = true, $data = '') {
    $arrTmp = $arr;
    $arr1 = $arr2 = array();
    if (strlen(trim($data)) > 0) {
        $keys = array_keys($arr);
        if (!$splitByKey) {
            $data = array_search($data, $arr);
        }
        $posK = array_search($data, $keys);
        if ($posK !== false) {
            if ($posK == 0) {
                $posK++;
            }
            $arr1 = array_splice($arrTmp, 0, $posK);
            $arr2 = array_splice($arr, $posK);
        }
    }

    return array($arr1, $arr2);
}

var_dump(splitArray($arr, true, $k));
var_dump(splitArray($arr, false, $v));
```